# Can mutt run external scripts based upon inbox rules?

Tags: mutt

I would like my mutt e-mail client to run a shell script when I receive an e-mail from a specific sender with a specific subject.

For example, when a message from foo@domain.com appears in my inbox, with a subject line matching "^Alert", mutt should run a script named `~/start-alert-process.sh`.

Looking at the `folder-hook` documentation, I don't see a way to run an external script from mutt. Is there a better, or different, way to have mutt to run shell scripts when particular conditions are met?

Comment: There is no way to do that with mutt. The folder hooks are only triggered if you *enter* the folder, not when a message arrives in that folder. It's pretty straight forward if you route you mail through maildrop or procmail, though.

Comment: Note of course the importance and significant challenges of writing such a script securely, since it would essentially be an open internet server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's an open and assigned feature request for the mutt dev team to add the ability to run a script when a new message is received:

- http://dev.mutt.org/trac/ticket/3573

But as of today, it is not possible.